# How to filter treeview with ObservableCollection data

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, treeview

I have done a treeview sample and would like to get the result that was shown at below:

There have a group of checkboxs (Green, Yellow & Red) and being checked. Then, have a treeview.
As you can see, if one of it's child contains red / yellow color, their parent turn to same color node also. For example, Class A with red node, because Student 3 it's node was red color.

[image]

How to implement filter tree view function in WPF c# ?

example result,

If I unchecked Green checkbox, the result will be:

[image]

If I unchecked green and yellow, the result will be:

[image]

Can get the treeview sample, at here

[TreeView Sample](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=233E2A690341BB1D&id=233E2A690341BB1D%21264)

***Main Window XAML***

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox Content="Green" Margin="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="Yellow" Margin="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="Red" Margin="2" IsChecked="True" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Class}" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
                <Border Width="150" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="2" Padding="2" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <Image Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Student}">
                <Border Width="132" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="26"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Margin="2"  Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"></TextBlock>

                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you use a collection in your ViewModel to fill the data of your TreeView? If so, please add it in your question.

Comment: @André Silva hi, yes I have used ObservableCollection with treeview, sample source code uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

So, you'd need to keep track of TWO collections -- one being the "Filtered" ObservableCollcetion, and the other being the "Master" ObservableCollection (which has the COMPLETE tree).

So, whenever you're binding to an ItemsSource for the TreeView, you'll need to be binding to the FilteredObservableCollection.  By default, this collection will be initialized with ALL of the items in the MasterObservableCollection.

When someone changes a Checkbox (and its binding is reflected in your ViewModel, i.e. IsRed = false), you'd have something on your ViewModel update the FilteredObservableCollection.  You would clear ALL items from the FilteredObservableCollection and then loop through the MasterObservableCollection, adding the items that match the criteria into it.

So, some brief pseudo-code from your ViewModel...

```
ObservableCollection<MyItem> MasterCollection;
ObservableCollection<MyItem> FilteredCollection;
bool IsRed, IsYellow, IsGreen; 

UpdateFilteredCollection()
{
    FilteredCollection.Clear();

    foreach( MyItem item in MasterCollection )
    {
        if( ( item.Color == Green && IsGreen ) || ( item.Color == Yellow && IsYellow ) || ( item.Color == Red && IsRed ) )
        {
            FilteredCollection.Add( item );
            /*
               And do this for child items, etc -- you'll probably
               have to rebuild the tree/MyItem's since some items
               will not appear under their parents;

               So this might look more like:

            FilteredCollection.Add( new MyItem()
                                    {
                                       Color = item.Color,
                                       Label = item.Label 
                                    } );
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Locke, because of my current implementation was using observable collection and based on you solution given when doing filter need clear and reconstruct the tree view (re-add item into collection). Are there any other ways to do it ?

Comment: You could perhaps have a XAML DataTemplate for each type (Hierarchical) and then try to set the Height of the item (if it is bound to IsRed, IsGreen, etc) to 0 and hide visibility.  However, I don't think that would adjust the actual TreeViewItem -- only the item displayed *within* -- so you'd end up having white-space where the Item should be.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a filter predicate for all nodes of a treeview hierarchy. Below I am providing an extension method you can call to set the filter function like this: `myTreeView.Filter(FilterPredicate);`. Of course in the filter predicate you need to distinguish between the different types of treeview nodes of your hierarchical data model.

Your predicate could look like this:

```cs
private bool FilterPredicate(object node) {
  if (node is Students) {
    return true; // always show nodes of level 0
  }
  else if (node is Student) {
    return (node as Student).Name.StartsWith(_searchText);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Here is the extension method on TreeViewItem to set the filter on all TreeViewItems of the hierarchy recursively:

```cs
public static class TreeViewExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Applies a search filter to all items of a TreeView recursively
    /// </summary>
    public static void Filter(this TreeView self, Predicate<object> predicate)
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(self.ItemsSource);
        if (view == null)
            return;
        view.Filter = predicate;
        foreach (var obj in self.Items) {
           var item = self.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as TreeViewItem;
           FilterRecursively(self, item, predicate);
        }
    }

    private static void FilterRecursively(TreeView tree, TreeViewItem item, Predicate<object> predicate)
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(item.ItemsSource);
        if (view == null)
            return;
        view.Filter = predicate;
        foreach (var obj in item.Items) {
           var childItem = tree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as TreeViewItem;
           FilterRecursively(tree, childItem, predicate);
        }
    }
}
```